# How to convert bootRepackage task to kotlin DSL in gradle 5.0.0?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-dsl

Looking to create a spring boot fat jar, but unsure how to convert the `bootRepackage` task found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration) in my `build.kts` file:

```
bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'demo.Application'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New day, new discovery. Spring Boot docs show that the `bootRepackage` task has been replaced by `bootJar` in 2017 and the `bootJar` task comes out of the box with the spring boot gradle plugin.

> The bootRepackage task has been replaced with bootJar and bootWar
>   tasks for building executable jars and wars respectively

**build.gradle.kts**

```
// option 1
tasks {
    getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
        classifier = "boot"
        mainClassName = "com.example.Application"
    }
}

// option 2
tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    classifier = "boot"
    mainClassName = "com.example.Application"
}
```

Comment: As of gradle 5.1, classifier is deprecated. `tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    archiveClassifier.set("boot")
    mainClassName = "com.example.Application"
}`